# selecting test file (jmx file) not working with jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to select only one JMeter test file (jmx file) to run at one time. I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <testFilesIncluded>
                    <jMeterTestFile>ionix-${foo.bar}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                </testFilesIncluded>
                <overrideRootLogLevel>DEBUG</overrideRootLogLevel>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have multiple jmx files in `src/test/jmeter`. It turns out those jmx files are always run by the jmeter plugin no matter what, even if I run maven with command like below:
`mvn clean -Dfoo.bar=nonsense jmeter:jmeter`

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Selecting-Tests-To-Run#specifying-testfilesincluded), my settings above should only execute `ionix-${foo.bar}.jmx`. (Whether the file `ionix-${foo.bar}.jmx` exists doesn't seem to make a difference in my case.) So, what am I missing here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug in Maven by adding -X to see what is happening .

could you list content of folder that contains jmx files